# c# async - Halting multiple tasks until one has completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, windows-store-apps, async-await

I have an app that is downloading images from a server and storing them locally if the image is not already locally stored. For the sake of this example lets say I have a number of images with the same name. I only want to download them once and store them once.
At the moment my app is downloading them each time its requested - for the sake of argument 10 requests made to the server for imageX.png. When the requests come back the app is trying to store them as imageX.png in application data folder. This is where my problem starts because more than one thread is trying to write to the same file at the same time.

Here is the code I currently have

```
    public static async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapImage( string folderName, string fileName )
    {
        if( await FileExists( "\\Assets\\" + folderName, fileName ) )
        {
            return new BitmapImage( new Uri( Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + "/Assets/" + folderName + "/" + fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute ) );
        }
        else
        {
            // Download and save locally
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.mywebsite.com/request.php?action=getImage&name=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode( fileName ) );
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync( request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead );
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
            {
                InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                DataWriter writer = new DataWriter( randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt( 0 ) );
                writer.WriteBytes( await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync() );
                await writer.StoreAsync();

                await image.SetSourceAsync( randomAccessStream );

                var folderObj = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync( Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + "\\Assets\\" + folderName );
                var imageFile = await folderObj.CreateFileAsync( fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting );
                var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync( FileAccessMode.ReadWrite );
                writer = new DataWriter( fs.GetOutputStreamAt( 0 ) );
                writer.WriteBytes( await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync() );
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                writer.DetachStream();
                await fs.FlushAsync();
            }
            return image;
        }
    }
```

What I suspect I need is to halt the thread before "if FileExists" until the previous thread has completed its task and saved to disk if necessary. The rest of the threads would then return true instantly on the FileExists call
Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I suspect I need is to halt the thread before "if FileExists" until the previous thread has completed its task and saved to disk if necessary.

If that's what you want to do, you can use a `SemaphoreSlim` as a kind of `async`-compatible lock, as such:

```
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
  if (await FileExists(...))
  ...
}
finally
{
  semaphore.Release();
}
```

However, this will limit *all* your downloads to one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 10 tasks running (each downloading a different image), and you want to process something sequentially as soon as each one of them completes:

```
Task[] tasks = //...

while(tasks.Length != 0) {

    int index = Task.WaitAny(taks);
    var completedTask = tasks[index];
    var image = completedTask.Result;

    //save to file

    var tasksList = tasks.ToList();
    tasksList.RemoveAt(index);
    tasks = tasksList.ToArray();

}
```

Comment: What is `RemoteAt`? I thought it might be a typo for `RemoveAt`, but that still wouldn't make sense, because `RemoveAt` doesn't return anything.